# Custom titlebar icon Windows 10

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a custom titlebar like Windows 10. But it looks bad, how I can fix this:

[image: this]

to this:

[image: this]

Comment: Can't you add code showing what you have tried and explain what you want visualy?

Comment: the code is base on [qtmodern](https://github.com/gmarull/qtmodern). I just change the buttons to image in stylesheet

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions and always remember that StackOverflow is not a place where you should ask "I found this but it doesn't do what I want, can you tell me what to do?". Show us some research effort, what you actually tried to achieve what you want, which obviously doesn't mean just telling us "I changed the images". Edit your question, give more context and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it will be probably closed in a matter of hours.